# Laptop beeps continuously during boot or while in BIOS when fan is running

Tags: boot, laptop, motherboard, bios, fan

When I boot my laptop (Clevo W230SS) and enter BIOS; or when I boot my laptop and my operating system (GNU/Linux) is not yet fully loaded (e.g. because I'm still typing in my password for LUKS); then sometimes the fan starts running and immediately after, the laptop starts **beeping continuously many many times** (– I'd guess around 20 times –) before it then **shuts down** (in both cases: in BIOS as well as at the LUKS prompt).

(Maybe the worst is that I just installed a new Linux-distro but I can't boot it because my laptop shuts down before I typed in my password because at the moment I have to type in my LUKS password twice (for GRUB and for Linux) which takes too long.)

[Here's a video demonstration on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE2FFa5hyLY). It also shows some BIOS settings.

What could be the reason for this? How does it relate to the fan? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Here's a BIOS update for your laptop. (please ensure this is the proper BIOS before flashing, as I've done about 30 minutes of research confirming it's correct, I take no responsibility if it is not) [BIOS 1.03.08](https://repo.palkeo.com/clevo-mirror/W230SS/B0308.zip)

Comment: By the way, the problem remains after removing a dust bunny while cleaning the fan.

Comment: @Hydranix, thanks, I'll check it out. It's strange though, that the new BIOS version isn't officially available from Clevo directly.

Comment: As with any strange mirrors of things, download at your own risk. Even says so on the main site